# How do you change the initial view controller in an ios application based on a remote notification?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, apple-push-notifications

I have an application that is implementing remote notifications.  My desire is to change the initial view controller based on one of three conditions: the user started the app on their own (no notifications); or, the user received an suspicious activity alert; or, the user received a crime alert.  I have implemented the application didReceiveRemoteNotification: method in the appDelegate.  Based on the notification and the user response to the notification I have implemented the following code:

```
UITabBarController *tbContr = (UITabBarController*) self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navContr = [tbContr.viewControllers][2];
ViewCrimesController *viewCrimes = [navContr.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewCrimes"];
[navContr presentViewController:viewCrimes animated:YES completion:nil];

[self.window.makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The problem I am having is that the navigation controls -- ie, the back button and the navigation bar title; are not on the ViewCrimesController when it is presented.  I have tried to load the ViewCrimesController many different ways.  Each way I get either and error saying there is no segue (this view is a model view to map view) or I am attempting to load the over an active view or, again, I don't get the navigation controls.

Do I need to specifically program the navigation controls or am I missing something in the way I am attempting to load the view?

I have seen references to dynamically changing the initial view in other posts.  But I have not seen anything that indicates specific programming is required to add the controls.  Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Susan

Comment: you're probably seeing warnings on this code where you access the viewControllers without a cast.  also, could you describe better what you want to happen?  e.g. of the form:  'I have N tabs, each is a navigation controller.  When some notification condition happens I want X to be the first thing visible'.

Comment: can u elaborate this "The problem I am having is that the navigation controls -- ie, the back button and the navigation bar title; are not on the ViewCrimesController when it is presented"

Comment: You are asking for the `ViewCrimes` controller - presumably in your scoreboard this is embedded in a navigation controller. As you are instantiating the `ViewCrimes` controller directly you are not getting the wrapping `UINavigationController`

Comment: @Paul.s, thank you.  Your comment put me on the right track.  Ultimately what I did was to remove the instantiating of the ViewCrimes controller and instead instantiated a second navigation controller from the storyboard with the embedded ViewCrimes controller.  So, I eliminated the 'ViewCrimesController *viewCrimes'... and replaced it with 'UINavigationController *nv = [navContr.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navcrimes";'

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the post, [Programmatically set the initial view controller using Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards)

The answer from that post may solve your issue,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *viewController = // determine the initial view controller here and instantiate it with [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:<storyboard id>];

   self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

   return YES;
}
```

You can also [download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58723521/SampleDetailView.zip) this sample, and implement it as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

simply change the key window's rootViewController, sample code placed here, hope it helps:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rootNavigationController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
```