# How to choose UIViewController after Spash Screen?

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to choose `UIViewController` after `Spash Screen` executed. For example:
After `Splash Screen` executed

```
if (condition) {
   call UIViewController2
}else{
   call UIViewController2
}
```

I found a correct information here [Programmatically set the initial view controller using Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards) and worked. Thanks for all

Comment: Do it in **Appdelegate.m**'s `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. It will call when your app has been launched.

Comment: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];` where `self.navigationController` is a `UINavigationController` and viewController is your `UIViewController`.

Comment: I am using StoryBoard and show this message error : "Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'MainStoryboard' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
BOOL condition;

if(condition) {
   UIViewController2 *v2 = [[UIViewController2 alloc] init];

   [self presentingViewController:v2 completion:nil];  // iOS 6.0 +
   [self presentModalViewController:v2 animated:YES];  // iOS 2.0, but depreciated in iOS 6
}
else {
   // not fully sure what you're asking for this part, but do the same as above
   // if you're looking for the same view controller
}
```

Comment: `presentModalViewController:` it should not be as IOS 3.0+ as IOS 6.0 is also greater than 3.0. It should be less than 6

Comment: I am using StoryBoard and show this message error : "Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'MainStoryboard' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set"

Comment: i was trying to give different ways of showing the view controller. they didn't say the iOS they are using

Answer (score 0):

this may help you:

import in your viewController.h  the ViewController target and give in storyboard an identifier:

```
  if(condition) {

   viewController1 *v1 = (viewController1 *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view1"];
   [self presentViewController:v1 animated:YES completion:nil];
  }

 else {

 // same code but with other viewController
 }
```