# How to implement tow storyBoards ? ios

Tags: ios, storyboard, xib, nib

if the user open the app for the first time I want to display welocome screen.
if this the second time I want to display the Home screen.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    if(first time)
    {
       //display welcome screen
    }

    if(second time)
    {
      //display Home screen.
    }

}
```

is this possible using storyboards ?
or I should use xib ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible using both Storyboard and Nibs (xibs).

Here's the solution for Storyboards (also, take a look a the [`UIStoryboard` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html)):

With a `Welcome.storyboard` and `Home.storyboard` in your app bundle, this would look something like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    NSString *storyboardName;
    if(first time)
    {
        storyboardName = @"Welcome";

    }
    else if(second time)
    {
        storyboardName = @"Home";
    }

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *rootViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    // Classic window.rootViewController dance here
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but what should I set the Main Interface in the deployment Info ! empty?

Comment: Yes keep it empty, and set the `rootViewController` of the `UIWindow` manually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards

Answer (score 2):

You can use UserDefaults to save save the state. I would not recommend to use Storyboard, simple design all screens in separated nibs.

```
#define kUserDefaultsHideWelcomeScreen @"welcomeScreen"

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

   if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: kUserDefaultsHideWelcomeScreen]) {

     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey: kUserDefaultsHideWelcomeScreen];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

     //display welcome screen
   } else {
     // display home screen
   }
}
```

Comment: I know How to check if this is the first time, I just want to know How to ask ios to start the home screen , or to start the welcome screen!