# Storyboard: setting the initial view controller at runtime

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, nib

I'm developing an iOS 7+ app, and I've been told to set a different initial view for the app depending on a parameter I won't know until runtime. One of the possible initial `UIViewController` is an `UITabBarViewController`, and the other one is an `UINavigationController`.

Is it possible to manage this using a `storyboard`? Or is it the only way to use separated `nib` files?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programatically set the initial view controller using Storyboards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use separate nib files, I do the same by following code in AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
    if(condition1) {
        UITabBarController *rootViewController= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabbarController"];
        [self setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    } else if(condition2) {
        UIViewController *rootViewController= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        [self setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    } else {
        UIViewController *rootViewController= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
        [self setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    }
}

-(void)setRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController {
    self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the ID for your UITabBarViewController and UINavigationController in the storyboard.Then manually set the rootViewController of your app as the code below.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIStoryboard *board = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.window.rootViewController = [board instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TabBarController"];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you right, but try to use [JLRoutes](https://github.com/joeldev/JLRoutes). Set your TabBarController as initial view controller in one storyboard and navigation controller will be initial in other storyboard. Then navigate between them using JLRoutes