# How to start app on another view controller after initial launch?

Tags: xcode, swift, viewcontroller, launch

I'm using Swift.

When my app is opened for the first time, I want it to go to the `WelcomeController`. However, now that the app has been launched once, I want the app to launch on a different view controller.

How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards

Answer (score 0):

The commented question from 68cherries details the mechanics of how to go to a specific view controller when the app launches. As to how to determine whether or not to show the WelcomeController or another one, I'd suggest storing a boolean flag in NSUerDefaults once the WelcomeController has been viewed. Then the next time the app starts, you can check if that flag is true and if so show the other controller instead.