# Swift show tutorialView on initialAppLaunch

Tags: swift, uistoryboardsegue

Now, I have seen [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards) about this same topic, however I need a little more clarification.

I have my storyboard set up with a `UINavigationController` as my initial view controller. My first displayed view I call `HomeViewController`. On the first app launch I would like to start with the `TutorialViewController` but then be able to have the user `dismissViewController` and see the home view. My initial reaction is to test a boolean set in user defaults from the `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` in the `HomeViewController` and then call a modal segue to the `TutorialViewController`,

```
if let myObject : AnyObject = def.objectForKey("noob"){
}else{
    let tutView : TutViewController = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController");
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("jumpTut", sender: self);
}
```

however this looks weird as you see the home viewController for a split second and then get jerked over to the `TutorialViewController`. I also get warnings like:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <MemoryLane.TutViewController: 0x17d746b0> on <UINavigationController: 0x17d73480> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Any ideas on how I should set all this up?

Comment: Please show your full code here.

Comment: I just updated the question