# change storyboard entry point

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have an app with `TabBarController` as its entry point with 2 tabs in it.

Requirements have changed and I need to add a login screen before showing this `TabBarController`.

How can I change the storyboard entry point ? Is it possible to do it programmatically ?

Comment: In this case you don't need to change the entry point, in my opinion. Just show the login screen modally in the first tab when the user is not logged in. If you still like to change the entry point, there is a check box in the Attributes Inspector called "Is Initial View Controller".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards
Or this can help

Comment: Or you can just drag the "entry arrow" to the desired view controller.

Comment: Solution in First comment did not work as I still see the Tab buttons on the bottom. Third suggestion worked. But I ended up figuring out how to add a new `ViewController`, bind it with my existing `DigitsViewController` in code and then dragged the entry point in new controller scene.