# SwiftSpinner no longer working

Tags: ios, swift

I was looking for a way to programmatically set my initial view controller using Storyboards. I found this solution: [Programmatically set the initial view controller using Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards)

This works just liked I want it to but after using the Swift answer provided in that topic:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var exampleViewController: ExampleViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ExampleController") as! ExampleViewController

self.window?.rootViewController = exampleViewController

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

return true
}
```

When loading the view for the first time the framework that used to work won't work anymore: SwiftLoader. https://github.com/leoru/SwiftLoader

However when I load the same view for the second time the SwiftLoader plugin does activated.

I load SwiftLoader like so:

```
SwiftLoader.show(title: "Loading...", animated: true)
```

I've the feeling that it has to do with the code above creating a UIWindow instead of whatever Storyboard used to (UIView?) do but I've no idea as to how to fix this?

Comment: Can you report on your question the portion of code when you show the indicator view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftLoader presents using the application's key window. See [this source code](https://github.com/leoru/SwiftLoader/blob/9947a409d7c63cf8c9af5161b258fc0e1f1fe477/src/SwiftLoader/SwiftLoader.swift#L50):

```
    var currentWindow : UIWindow = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!

    // […snip…]

    loader.coverView = UIView(frame: currentWindow.bounds)
    loader.coverView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    if (loader.superview == nil) {
        currentWindow.addSubview(loader.coverView!)
        currentWindow.addSubview(loader)
        loader.start()
    } else {
        loader.coverView?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
```

So your problem must be that another window is the *key* window when you first activate SwiftLoader.

To check this, inspect `UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow` and compare it to the `UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows` array to see what all of the current windows in your app are. The frontmost `UIWindow` will be the last element of this array.

Non-key windows might be iOS keyboards, alert views, etc.

I fixed a similar problem in [the SVProgressHUD library by implementing this code](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVProgressHUD/blob/master/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.m#L610-L620):

```
    NSEnumerator *frontToBackWindows = [UIApplication.sharedApplication.windows reverseObjectEnumerator];
    for (UIWindow *window in frontToBackWindows){
        BOOL windowOnMainScreen = window.screen == UIScreen.mainScreen;
        BOOL windowIsVisible = !window.hidden && window.alpha > 0;
        BOOL windowLevelNormal = window.windowLevel == UIWindowLevelNormal;

        if (windowOnMainScreen && windowIsVisible && windowLevelNormal) {
            [window addSubview:self.overlayView];
            break;
        }
    }
```

You might want to update SwiftLoader to use smarter logic like this (ported to Swift), or allow you to manually specify a window.