# Set rootViewController based on condition

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently working on an application in Xcode 7.2, iOS 9.2 using Swift. I want to have a screen pop up the very first time the user opens the application and get some data and store it permanently. I found a thread where someone asked something similar: [Programmatically set the initial view controller using Storyboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards/27343365#27343365.I) have followed the instructions closely, but I can't seem to get it to work the way I want it to.

Here is the modified code from my AppDelegate.swift file.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds);
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
    var initialViewController: UIViewController;
    print(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("firstTime"));
    if(!NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("firstTime")){
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstTimeScreen");
    } else {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Dashboard");
    }
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController;
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible();
    return true
}
```

In the ViewController.swift file corresponding to the ViewController that should open from the second time onwards, in the viewDidLoad() method, I have the following line of code:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "firstTime");
```

Currently the first screen is always opening. The screen which should from the second time onwards is not the root view controller even though the NSUserDefaults value is tested.

I started the application working on a single view controller, and I currently do not have any Navigation Controllers or anything. Just a bunch of individual View Controllers, connected through button segues.

Thank you for taking the time to read this and possibly answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `firstTime` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
    if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("firstTime") == nil){
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstTimeScreen");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "firstTime");
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    } else {
        initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Dashboard");
    }
```

Comment: @Morgoth Did you try `objectForKey` as my edited answer

Comment: Yes, I was just about to post an answer with that code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Looking closely at your logic here, there is a `!` in the if statement, which means if `firstTime` is not true it will show the view controller with identifier `FirstTimeScreen`. You'll want to remove the !, so that it will show the `FirstTimeScreen` when it is the first time launching.

Be sure that you store `false` for `firstTime` in the `FirstTimeScreen`, not `Dashboard`.

Also be sure you register NSUserDefaults with `firstTime` set to `true`, otherwise it will be `false` and never show your `FirstTimeScreen`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "firstTime" to true, instead of false:
`NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "firstTime");`

Also, make sure you use `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()` after that to save the changes.