# XCTest UI Testing: Jump Straight to One View Controller

Tags: xcode, swift, xctest

I have a complex app. I would like to test just one view controller in a new UI test I'm writing.

What is the best way to get that one view controller on the screen so I can test against it? Using *record* and emulating all the user interaction to get to that view controller is not practical.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no other way.

Comment: I think the answer is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards

Comment: That won't work in a UI Test. You can't change the code that's about to be executed in a UI test.