# Using UISwitch for changing the initial ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uiswitch

I wanted to ad an option into my application to change the initial ViewController so users can skip the login view.

```
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

var vc: UIViewController?

@IBOutlet var changeInitialView: UISwitch?

@IBAction func changeButton(sender: UIButton) {
    if changeInitialView!.on {
        print("Switch is off")
        vc = UIStoryboard(name: "MenuViewController", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController")
        changeInitialView!.setOn(false, animated:true)
    } else {
        print("Switch is on")
        changeInitialView!.setOn(true, animated:true)
    }
}
```

if I try it like this, it always shows me this fail message:
Could not find a storyboard named 'MenuViewController' in bundle ...

Answer (score 0):

First VC is a `UIViewController` object and second I think `MenuViewController` is your `viewcontroller`'s name not the storyboard name.
Try following the below steps :

1. Initially you must have an initial VC from where your app flow will start.
2. Now if you want to change the initial VC when next time your app is launched, just create a flag and store its value in `NSUserDefaults`.
3. in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, check the flag in `NSUserDefaults` and accordingly set your initial VC.

The code for step 3, is shown in the link which I had shared earlier.

Comment: Yeah I've also tried with the name in the storyboard ("Menu") but this doesn't work as well.

What do you mean with vc is a UIViewController object? do I have to change there something?

Comment: what is storyboard name?

Comment: The Storyboard name is "Menu"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428629/programatically-set-the-initial-view-controller-using-storyboards, see if this can help you.

Comment: Thx but now I get an error because it don't find the name of the first initial ViewController. It's just the same error then now but it shows allready when starting the app. Somehow I dont' write the right name, but I have tried the title as well as the ID

Comment: thanks for your help. but all I try also with the link you shared ends with the error _Could not find a storyboard named '...' in bundle ..._