# Firebase addStateDidChangeListener in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, appdelegate, nsnotifications

I am trying to configure the `addStateDidChangeListener` in my app. I read in the [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start) that I should be able to attach the listener in the `ViewController`'s `viewWillAppear()` method and detach the listener in the `ViewController`'s `viewWillDisappear()` method. Is it possible to set this up in the `AppDelegate` since my app will need to check for a user in many different `ViewControllers`?

I originally thought to attach the listener in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()` method, but found an answer about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49797274/6063755) on StackOverflow. I am a bit confused as to how this answer's code will allow me to do checks in a `ViewController`. The code is as follows:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.AuthStateDidChange, object: Auth.auth(), queue: nil) { (_) in
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    }
    return true
}
```

First, is the above code considered to be a correct way to set up the following Firebase method:

```
handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
  // ...
}
```

Second, how can I access this `NSNotification` in my `ViewControllers`?

Third, where do I detach both the `NSNotification` and the listener? Is it in the `applicationWillTerminate()` method, the `applicationWillResignActive()` method, or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be better if you design it in a better way but let me help you with the current structure.

First, since you use the notification, all you have to do is to post notification call when you get the callback from the method.

Second, how notification works is you post it somewhere in the code and you add observer in view controllers when you need it. You can access this notification by setting observers in the said view controllers.

Third, that's up to you actually. If detaching observers when the app goes into the background, then you should do it. If you do so, you have to set it up when it becomes active.

Comment: If you could offer up your opinion on a better way or provide some code to supplement your ideas, that would be awesome!