# Auto login with FirebaseUI on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I'm following the documentation here to use FirebaseUI to show sign-in screens on an iOS app.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui?authuser=2

How do I automatically sign-in a user after they have already signed-in before without having to present this UI each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firebase Auth SDK will persist login information between app launches.  However, the signed in user isn't available immediately when the app launches.  What you should do is establish an auth state listener using [addStateDidChangeListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#addstatedidchangelistener_:) to find out when the an authenticated is definitely signed in or not.

This pattern can be seen in this other question: [Checking Firebase current signed-in user via Listener in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531271/checking-firebase-current-signed-in-user-via-listener-in-ios)

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
  if let user = user {
    // User is signed in. Show home screen
  } else {
    // No User is signed in. Show user the login screen
  }
}
```

The block will be invoked when the state of the user is first known, so you can use that to decide then whether or not to preset the sign-in screen.