# Making project created in Xcode 11 backwards compatible

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11

I've created a new project using Xcode 11. I'm used to creating my `UIWindow`'s root view controller programmatically and I first noticed this new SceneDelegate file. After some research I found an article describing how to create root view controller using this new `UIScene` API and it seems to work properly. However, I couldn't find a way to do the same thing for lower iOS versions because AppDelegate class now does not have a `window` property anymore. So my question is how do I create a root view controller programmatically for other iOS versions?

Comment: `UIScene` is iOS13+ only, so if you want to support older OS-es, you'll need to manually add the `UIWindow` code.

Comment: See https://github.com/rmaddy/XcodeTemplates for an updated Single View App template that creates either a code or storyboard based app project that supports iOS 12 and 13. It supports both Swift and Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code if someone faces the same thing.

### iOS 13 workflow

Code taken from [this](https://medium.com/@ZkHaider/apples-new-uiscene-api-a-programmatic-approach-52d05e382cf2) article.

In your SceneDelegate file:

```swift
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        self.window?.windowScene = windowScene

        let controller = UIViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)

        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

### iOS 12 and lower

In your AppDelegate file:

```swift
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) { return true }

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

        let controller = UIViewController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)

        self.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

It is important to hold `UIWindow` in a variable in order for it to show up.

Comment: This answer is only a start. It is not complete. `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called under both iOS 12 and 13. But you do not want to create the window or root view controller there under iOS 13.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58208876/1226963 for a proper setup.