# iOS 12 / 13 Programmatic View Creation

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplicationdelegate

My apps uses no Storyboards. All views are created programmatically.

Historically I have deleted my `Main.storyboard`, removed the reference from my `Info.plist` and setup my `UIWindow` and `rootViewController` as follows:

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        self.window = window

        return true
    }
```

However when trying to run my app in iOS 13, I get a crash -

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main' in bundle NSBundle </Users/Dev/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8A4474B1-FCA3-4720-8F34-A6975A03EE19/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/258FA246-A283-4FE6-A075-58BD32424427/Home.app> (loaded)'
***
```

iOS 12 still runs as expected. How should I setup my view programmatically to support iOS 12 and 13?

Comment: Please check in your Target->General Tab ->Deployment Info->Main Interface. it may be Main.Storyboard

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58208876/1226963 for the general pattern you need. Even easier, see https://github.com/rmaddy/XcodeTemplates for a template that support iOS 12 & 13, both Swift and Objective-C, and either code-only or storyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add update `SceneDelegate.swift` also.

Update `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)` and add

```swift
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        let viewController = ViewController()
        window.rootViewController = viewController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        self.window = window
```

Comment: This is not quite right. You must use the `UIWindow` initializer that takes a window scene. And as a result you do not need the `window.windowScene = windowScene` line.

Comment: Excellent spot, I've updated my answer. Thanks for pointing that out 