# iOS13 App black screen, self.window not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

After my test iPhone device upgrade to version 13.3, my `self.window` is not working anymore. I have tried as follows:

1. select TARGETS -> General -> Deployment Info, clean "Main Interface".
2. Deleted "Storyboard name -> main" in info.plist, deleted "Main storyboard file base name" in info.plist, deleted anything related to main.storyboard in info.plist.
3. Add code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = KWhiteColor;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

But still get black screen when launch App. Is there anybody who can tell me why and how to make `self.window` work?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    //初始化window
//    [self initWindow];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = KWhiteColor;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    //初始化服务
    [self initService];

    //初始化用户系统
//    [self initUserManager];
    CSKLoginViewController *vc = [CSKLoginViewController new];
    //        vc.showBack = NO;
//    RootNavigationController *loginNavi = [[RootNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;

    return YES;
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>xxx</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>zh_CN</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
    <string>访问您的通讯录新增客户。</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>SceneDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: are you using the XIB or would you want to create your VC progrmatically

Comment: please share all the relevant data in your AppDelegate

Comment: My VC all created progrmatically.

Comment: move this line to  `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; return YES;` and try
`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;

    return YES;
}
```

info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It's ok on my side.

Comment: I created a new project and made a test like yours, but still black screen. I don't know why.

Comment: if u use Xcode11 to create new project, you should set window in scene delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Should write code in SceneDelegate.
https://medium.com/better-programming/creating-apps-without-storyboards-in-ios-13-fc9550bb9c12

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code is in the wrong place. The window no longer belongs to the app delegate; it belongs to the *scene* delegate.

Comment: I have given some sample scene delegate code for creating the root view controller without a storyboard here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58405507/341994