# SwiftUI willFinishLaunchingWithOptions has launchOptions = nil

Tags: swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios14

I have the app registered for Firebase notifications and I have implemented the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`. the `didReceive` method is called when the application is running or in the background.

When I terminate the application and send a notification. The `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` methods are called but launchOptions object is nil and does not contain any .remoteNotificaiton key.

```
if launchOptions != nil {
            logger.log("There is stuff in launch options")
        }
```

My AppDelegate Setup

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate 

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate 

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate
```

The above code never prints any log message to the console.

I have tried everything and google for whole but nothing concrete.

I am on iOS 14 beta 6 and Xcode beta 6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should not be there. Would you show code how/where you set up delegate? (Btw this workflow should be tested on a device - it does not work on simulator).

Comment: Yes, I am testing on real device not simulator.

Comment: @Asperi here is my AppDelegate updated the question with my AppDelegate setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get notification from SceneDelegate not AppDelegate with `connectionOptions.notificationResponse`

From
https://dev.to/nemecek_f/ios-13-launchoptions-always-nil-this-is-the-reason-solution-kki
& https://stackoverflow.com/a/61322065/12208004

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
   if let notificationResponse = connectionOptions.notificationResponse {
          // you can get notification here
        }        

        let contentView = ContentView()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
```

**[UPDATE]**
You can get notification from `userNotificationCenter` even when the app is not started

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("open notification")
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        print(userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
```