# iOS13: Universal Links not opening if the app was not running

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, ios-universal-links, universal-link

We have implemented handling of universal links in our app and I am struggling with the following issues:

- Universal Links opens when the app is running in the background **(working fine)**
- When running on the device with iOS13 installed, opening a universal link only works properly if the app is running in the background. If it has been terminated, after tapping the
  link the app is getting launched but this method not called

```
application(continue userActivity:.., restorationHandler:..)
```

Any ideas?

```
var window: UIWindow?   
var tabBarController1: UITabBarController?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
{
    presentAppLaunchVC()
    return true
}

func presentVC(navController : UINavigationController)
{
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        topController.present(navController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    

    if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb
    {
        guard let url = userActivity.webpageURL else {
            return false
        }
        if !isValidDeepLink(web_url: url)
        {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
        else
        {
            scrapDeepLinkingUrl(url : url)
        }
    }
    return true
}
func isValidDeepLink(web_url :URL) -> Bool
{
    
    guard let components = URLComponents(url : web_url,resolvingAgainstBaseURL : true) else {
        return  false
    }
    guard let host = components.host else {
        return false
    }
    switch host {
    case "www.domain.com":
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
func scrapDeepLinkingUrl(url : URL)
{
    }
    else
    {
        presentAppLaunchVC()
    }
}
func presentAppLaunchVC()
{
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboard_name, bundle: nil)
    let screen = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
    if identifier == "dashboardVC" {
        tabBarController1 = screen as? UITabBarController
    }
    self.window?.rootViewController = screen
}
```

Comment: You are not helping yourself by showing no line of code.

Comment: @ElTomato everything is working fine Appdelegates this method is also calling when the app is in the background state. but it is not calling when the app is completely closed or terminated

Comment: So you have no scene delegate?

Comment: @matt Project is old so I have only Appdelegate class.

Comment: Cool, just making sure (because if you did, it would get routed to the scene delegate).

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the URL in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method as well.

It can be an URL:
`launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]`

or it can be an Universal link:
`launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsUserActivityDictionaryKey]`

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add [conditional scene delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58405393/appdelegate-and-scenedelegate-when-supporting-ios-12-and-13/58405507#58405507) support. That way, you would get the message in `scene(_:willConnectTo:)`. Okay, this is going to be more work, but you need to get in sync with the native scene support in iOS 13 and later, and this seems to be the moment to do so.