# how to present view controller from appdelegate or scenedelegate in swift5?

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

how to present view controller from appdelegate or scenedelegate in swift5 ? 
i tried this but didnt work :

```
self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "profile")
                self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
                self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58208876/1226963 for an example.

Comment: But if you are using a storyboard, why are you adding code to show it? No code is needed for the main storyboard to be shown automatically on app startup.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? What is the error message?

Comment: no i want present view controller programmatically from appdelegate or scenedelegate . @rmaddy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're initializing the window's root view controller as the instantiated storyboard view.  You need to set your window's root view like so:

```
    self.window?.rootViewController = ProfileViewController()
```

This sets it directly to the swift file, which should be a `UIViewController` of some sort, and doesn't use the Storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to initialize your view controller.

```
window?.rootViewController = ViewController()
```

Are you doing this in SceneDelegate? If so, you can initialize your window with a windowScene

Source: https://youtu.be/2oo0tO1E9ys